# Sessão do PagSeguro com Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando pegar a sessão do PagSeguro usando o WebClient do Asp.Net MVC mas sempre lança uma exceção de erro que não estou conseguindo resolver.

**WebClient**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getSessaoPagSeguro() {

            try{
                //URI de sessao.
                string uri = PagSeguroCfg.PAGSEG_SANDBOX_SESSION;

                //Conjunto de parâmetros/formData.
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                postData.Add("email", PagSeguroCfg.PAGSEG_LOGIN);
                postData.Add("token", PagSeguroCfg.PAGSEG_SANDBOX_TOKEN);

                //String que receberá o XML de retorno.
                string xmlString = null;

                //Webclient faz o post para o servidor de pagseguro.
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    //Informa header sobre URL.
                    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1");

                    //Faz o POST e retorna o XML contendo resposta do servidor do pagseguro.
                    byte[] result = wc.UploadValues(uri, postData);

                    //Obtém string do XML.
                    xmlString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
                }

                //Cria documento XML.
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                //Carrega documento XML por string.
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

                //Obtém código de transação (Checkout).
                var code = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("id")[0];

                jsonResposta.Add("session", code.InnerText);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return Json(jsonResposta);
        }
```

**Exception**

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
O cabeçalho de Content-Type não pode ser alterado de seu valor padrão para esta solicitação.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2), é recomendável que utilize o HttpClient:

> **! Importante**
>
> Não é recomendável que você use o WebClient classe para novo
>   desenvolvimento. Em vez disso, use o [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)
>   classe.

Mas para seu problema. Na linha seguinte você está utilizando o Header:

```
//Informa header sobre URL.
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

A [documentação da API](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/guia-de-integracao/api-de-pagamentos.html#v2-item-api-de-pagamentos-parametros-http) do pagseguro explica, que o cabeçalho para uma requisição XML é diferente da HTTP:

**O cabeçalho Content-Type deve ser informado como no exemplo abaixo:**

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

> Observação: caso sua aplicação ou loja não utilize o conjunto de
>   caracteres ISO-8859-1, p.e.(UTF-8), é necessário substituir o
>   parâmetro charset do exemplo acima.